regex groups to capture key value pairs
I am looking to parse key value pairs from text using RE2 compliant regex. The text can be like below
[key 1]:  value 1[key 2]:  value 2 [with brackets] or {with curly brackets}{key 3}:  value 3 {with curly brackets} or [with square brackets] [key 4]: value 4 with :

The above text should be parsed as below key value pairs-
key 1 , value 1 
key 2 , value 2 [with brackets] or {with curly brackets}
key 3 , value 3 {with curly brackets} or [with square brackets] 
key 4 , value 4 with :

The keys are in square brackets or curly brackets that are followed by :
The values can be any type of printable characters including [] {} : .
I tried multiple regex group patterns and the one that I came up with fails to correctly capture values that have [] or {}
(?:\[(.*?)\]|\{(.*?)\}):[  ](.+?[^\[\]:]+?[^{}]+?)

https://regex101.com/r/CwsSKx/1
As the regex has to be RE2 compliant, lookahead symbols cannot be used in the solution.
Any help will be appreciated.

Do you really have to use nothing but regex?

This seems very difficult with just regexp. How do you know that [key 2] is the next key, rather than part of the first value?

Regular expressions are rarely a good solution to parsing text with such flexible formatting.

Regular expressions are used for pattern matching. As your text does not follow any sort of constant pattern, it's going to be near impossible to do anything with a regex.  Your rules remove any possibility of a pattern to match, as all possible delimiters that would help locate that pattern are also allowed in the text. You should be looking for alternatives, like the string functions in your programming language.

The question Barmar asked is the key.  If you can define the rules for dividing each pair from the other pairs, then we can get somewhere.  But how can that be done when the value can contain [, and {?  What sequence do you use to indicate the end of this pair's value and the start of the next pair?

Is the closing of a key always ]: or }:, and are these patterns invalid in the values?  Also, are the characters [ and { invalid in a key?  If so, then that might be doable.

That is correct. Closing of key will always be followed by ]: or }: . These patterns are invalid in values. Also, these patterns are invalid ina key.

@Barmar my previous comment should answer your question. Let me know if there is more clarity required.

I don't think you can do this without lookarounds as there's no way of confirming that the } after {with curly brackets is not the end of a key value without absorbing the { that indicates the start of the key 3 value. Unless there was guaranteed to be a character which was not a } or [ before the start of a key value?

Please provide the (programming?) environment or tool in which you will apply this regex.

@trincot it is golang

I think it's impossible to find matching only through regex. So, I tried different way to do this.

First use a pipe(|) character to point out position of key
        regex: str.replace(/(\S{1})?key/gi, '\|$&')
Next, you filter out data between pipe(|) characters
or split out the entire string using pipe(|) character 
        regex: str.match(/(?<![^|])[^|\n]*/gi) or str.split(/\|/gi)
You have an array of elements like:

[
   '[key 1]:  value 1', 
   '[key 2]:  value 2 [with brackets] or {with curly brackets}',
   '{key 3}:  value 3 {with curly brackets} or [with sqaure brackets]',
   'key 5]: value 5 data
]

Here, you have to trim brackets both side of key id, ([key \d+] → key \d+)

So, atlast, filter out specific part of each element in that array and trim brackets if it exist both side of key \d+:

  x.replace(/(\S)?key\s\d+(\S)?\:/gi,            // Find `[Key \d+]:` portion
       (x) => x = x.replace(/(\S)?key/gi, 'key') // Remove starting bracket
                   .replace(/(\S)?\:/gi, ':')    // Remove ending bracket
  )



function findMatching(st) {
   return st.replace(/(\S{1})?key/gi, '\|$&')
        .match(/(?<![^|])[^|\n]*/gi)
        // .split(/\|/gi)  // alternative of 'match'
        .filter(x => x).map(x => x.replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').trim())
        .map(x => x = 
             x.replace(/(\S)?key\s\d+(\S)?\:/gi, 
                 (x) => x = x.replace(/(\S)?key/gi, 'key')
                             .replace(/(\S)?\:/gi, ':')
             )
         );
}
const st1 = `[key 1]:  value 1[key 2]:  value 2 [with brackets] or {with curly brackets}{key 3}:  value 3 {with curly brackets} or [with sqaure brackets] [key 4]: value 4 with : key 5]: value 5 data`;
console.log(findMatching(st1));



I think this way, you will resolve the issue.
Thank You

This is not a JavaScript question.

I am sorry for the confusion but the key here doesn't literally mean the word "key". It could be any string like "Target", "Condition".
